# Python 2: adding integers in a FOR loop

Tags: python

I am working on lab in class and came across this problem:

**Write a program using a for statement as a counting loop that adds up integers that the user enters. First the program asks how many numbers will be added up. Then the program prompts the user for each number. Finally it prints the sum.**

I am having a lot of trouble answering this, if someone could help me that would be great, thank you!

So far I have written this:

```
    NumOfInt=int(raw_input("How many numbers would you like to add up?")) 
    for i in range(NumOfInt):
```

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Ask us a question. What specific aspect of the problem are you having trouble with? Have you tried anything that didn't work when you expected it to? You can't just post your assignment at us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
number = int(raw_input("How many numbers?"))
tot = 0

for x in range(number):
    tot += int(raw_input("Enter next number:"))
print tot
```

Comment: Just dumping code with no explanation is not a useful answer.

Comment: It's clear the OP understands how to get input and convert it to an integer. There is not much else to explain other than showing that is should be done again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking:

Write, using a for loop, a program that will ask the user how many numbers they want to add up. Then it will ask them this amount of times for a number which will be added to a total. This will then be printed.

If this is the case, then I believe you just need to ask the user for this amount of numbers and write the for loop in a similar fashion to your's:

```
NumOfInt = int(input("How many numbers would you like to add up? : "))
total = 0

for i in range (NumOfInt):
    newnum = int(input("Enter a number! : "))
    total += newnum

print("Your total is: " + str(total))
```

This will add their input to the total until the amount of numbers they have input exceeds NumOfInt:

```
How many numbers would you like to add up? : 4
Enter a number! : 1
Enter a number! : 2
Enter a number! : 3
Enter a number! : 4
Your total is: 10
```

I hope this helps :)